# What is a 'festival circuit'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a 'festival circuit'?

I have been browsing through the internet but the only meaning I have found is that 'festival circuit' is the same as 'festival'.

Any differences between the two?

Possible contexts:

"But then there are other filmmakers who don't take such a sunny approach to the film festival circuit. Certain filmmakers believe that the entrance fees and travel expenses involved with the festival circuit are a waste of resources, particularly regarding larger festivals such as Toronto, SXSW, or Sundance."

"Explore the international festival circuit. Gain exposure for your production, develop new contacts, and obtain recognition by participating in film festivals around the world."

Comment: The "festival circuit" consists of all the festivals.  One thing to do with your new film is to circulate it to many festivals.  If you look up "circuit" in a dictionary, you may find one of the definitions fits this.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. You could start by adding a relevant dictionary definition of 'circuit'.

Answer (score 2):

"Circuit" in this context refers to a series of different locations and events, almost similar to a "concert tour".

"Circuit" is used to imply a certain repetition (eg. circuit training in fitness). The word is used to indicate that someone attending the festival is usually interested in or obligated to "complete the circuit" of events for that industry.

Thus "festival circuit" means a series of festivals, events, locations and so on relevant to the industry, be it film, music, dance, clubs, technology, etc.

Comment: @Ewa I think this is a definition for it:                                                                                                                                          
a. A regular or accustomed course from place to place; a round: a salesperson on the Detroit-Minneapolis-Chicago circuit; a popular speaker on the lecture circuit.